# While loop issue while calling it multiple time in 1 request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model with a reference to it self and a method to get the 'chain' like this:

```rb
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Category', foreign_key: 'parent_id', optional: true
  has_many :children, class_name: 'Category', foreign_key: 'parent_id'

  def chain
    cat = self
    str = name
    while cat.parent
      str.prepend("#{cat.name}/")
      cat = cat.parent
    end
    str
  end
end
```

This method is working fine, untill I call it two or more times in one request. For example if I have these records:

ID Name Parent_id

1 Payments nil

2 2020 1

3 January 2

Now I want to move the category `January` to the category `Payments`, so `January` parent_id will become 1.

```rb
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  def update
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    @category.chain # => "Payments/2020/January"
    if @category.update(category_params)
      @category.chain # => "Payments/Payments/January"
      do_some_other_stuff
    end
  end

  private
  
  def category_params
    params.require(:category).permit(:name, :parent_id)
  end

  def do_some_other_stuff
    @category.chain # => "Payments/Payments/Payments/January"
  end
end
```

For every time I call it, it adds the category name to it. Anyone an idea why this is happening?

Comment: Can you show what `category_params` are

Comment: I don't understand how you're updating the parent if you're not accepting it in the params. What is the value for the `name` param you're passing in?

Comment: the `parent_id` is also in the permitted attributes, sorry. But that is not the problem. The value of `name` param is still `January` because I don't edit that, I only change the `parent_id`

Comment: I think you need to swap the `str.prepend` and `cat = cat.parent` lines. Otherwise, you start with `str = name` and prepend that same name because you haven't swapped the `cat` yet

Comment: You could implement as `def chain; return name unless parent; "#{parent.chain}/#{name}"; end` that being said this will result in N+1 so it would be better to determine a way to load all the objects first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One side effect you might not be aware of is that you are editing `name` when doing `str.prepend("#{cat.name}/")`.
See:
[image]

Try using `+` instead of `prepend`. Compare:
[image]

I guess that is the main problem. But also I tried running your code and it doesn't work the way you described. So I  can't be sure this will fix all issues. Did you post the exact code that gives you the correct result:`@category.chain # => "Payments/2020/January"`?

And in general, mutating is always risky, as it causes bugs that are hard to track, like this one. Consider a different implementation. For example, you could use recursion if you're up to it. Your entire chain method can be written as:

```
  def chain
    if parent
      parent.chain + "/" + name
    else
      name
    end
  end
```

Comment: That sounds pretty logic and I think it will solve my issue. Will try it when I'm back at work.